# Python Histogram of an array with 200 integers, error

Tags: python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
    
def integerlist():
   integerlist = np.array(np.random.uniform(low=-23, high=42, size=(200,)).astype(int))
   return np.ndarray.flatten(integerlist)

  print(integerlist())



def histogram():
 np.histogram(integerlist, bins = [-30,-20,-10,0,10,20,40,50])
 hist, bins = np.histogram(integerlist, bins = [-30,-20,-10,0,10,20,40,50])

 print(hist)
 print(bins)

 plt.hist(integerlist, [-30,-20,-10,0,10,20,40,50])
 plt.title("gleichverteilten Ganzzahlen")
 plt.show()
```

After running the code I get the following error: "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int'".
Does anyone now what the error in the code is?

Answer (score 0):

Read histogram docs: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html

First argument in `np.histogram(integerlist, bins = [-30,-20,-10,0,10,20,40,50])` must be array, you send function.

If you function create array add () to execute this function.

Answer (score 0):

`integerlist`, in the module (global) scope is a function, not a list. You have to invoke it to obtain the list you seek.
Thus, in your `histogram` function, replace

```
integerlist
```

With

```
integerlist()
```

Note, the overall code was not tested. You might still have other errors. Report for further help

Answer (score 0):

From the [NumPy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html):

> bins:  int or sequence of scalars or str, optional
>
> If bins is an int, it defines the number of equal-width bins in the given range (10, by default). If bins is a sequence, it defines a monotonically increasing array of bin edges, including the rightmost edge, allowing for non-uniform bin widths.

So you can try that:

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
#-*- /usr/bin/python3

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def integerlist():
    integerlist = np.array(np.random.uniform(low=-23, high=42, size=(200,)).astype(int))
    return np.ndarray.flatten(integerlist)

print(integerlist())

def histogram():
    np.histogram(integerlist, bins=[-30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 40, 50])
    hist, bins = np.histogram(integerlist, bins=[-30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 40, 50])

    plt.hist([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [-30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 40, 50])
    plt.title("gleichverteilten Ganzzahlen")
    plt.show()

histogram()
```